# jQuery: Select "a" of the "li" marked as "this"

Tags: jquery, select, html-lists

I work with an unordered list of links. When a user clicks on the 'li' tag that doesn't have .myclass ––

```
$('#access li:not(.myclass)').click(function(event) {
```

-- certain animated effects occur, and then I want to go to the url of the link associated with the 'li' tag that was clicked.

This code ––

```
var url = $(this).attr('href')
```

–– would get me the necessary url if I were initially selecting the 'a' - but for a certain number of reasons I have to select 'li'.

My attempt: `var url = $(this>'a').attr('href')` was obviously doomed to failure.

**Question: how can I get the 'href' attribute of the clicked 'li' element?**

I'd be grateful for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: a more concise version might be: `$('a',$(this)).attr('href');`

Comment: Even more concise is $('a', this).attr('href')

Comment: @Shad: `.find()` is so much more readable IMO, and slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find` method to find descendent elements:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href')
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#access li:not(".myClass")').click(function(){


});
```

If each `<li>` element has a href attribute.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, Felix, but thank you for being ready to help.